# Polymorphic Relationships are not Working in Laravel Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have setup new lumen v5.7 project and make models and define polymorphic relationhips in models but when I i fetch data morphTo relation not execue. But when same model architecture is used in Laravel Full version project then its work fine. But I have to work on lumen project instead of full laravel project.

Is there any way that polymorphic relationships work in lumen.

**Cutomized the model type**

```
public function register() {
        Relation::morphMap([
            'media' => \App\Morphic\Media::class,
            'text' => \App\Morphic\Text::class,
        ]);
    }
```

**Morphic model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Morphic;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {

    protected $primarykey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'user_posts';

    public function detail() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public static function getAllRecords() {
        $result = Post::with('detail')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(40)->get();
        return $result;

    }

}
```

**Post Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Media extends Model {

    protected $primarykey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'media_posts';
    protected $with = ['media'];

    public function media() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostMedia','user_post_id');
    }

    public function post() {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Morphic\Post', 'postable');
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error that show?

Comment: @atouiahmed no error show

Comment: did the code works well on laravel?

Comment: @atouiahmed yes work fine but not work on lumen only

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the Eloquent ORM, you should uncomment the `$app->withEloquent()` call in your `bootstrap/app.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

`AppServiceProvider` needed to be enabled  and i was using detail relation instead of `postable`. But when I modified these things relationships work fine.